# nginx setting for azure file upload in node server

Tags: node.js, azure, nginx

I am using mutiparty module for file upload to azure blob storage.

```
 var form = new multiparty.Form(),
        blobService = azure.createBlobService();
    form.uploadDir = dir.TMPDIR;
    form.maxFilesSize = process.env.maxFilesSize;
    var files = [];
    var chunks = [];
    var totalLength = 0;

    var fileName;
    var tmpFile;
    form.on('part', function (part){
        if (!part.filename) return;

        fileName = generateGUID() + '.'+fileExt(part.filename);
        tmpFile = dir.TMPDIR + '/' + fileName;
        part.on('data', function(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
            totalLength += chunk.length;
        });
        uploadName = part.filename;
        var size = part.byteCount - part.byteOffset;
        uploadType = part.headers['content-type'];
        fileName = generateGUID() + '.'+fileExt(part.filename);
        tmpFile = dir.TMPDIR + '/' + fileName;

        blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('videos', fileName, part, size, function(error, result, response) {
            if (error) {
              return  res.status(500).send();
            }

            res.json({file: mediaContainer.host +'videos/' + fileName});


        });

    });
    form.parse(req);
```

on production i am using nginx.
When i am uploading upto 50 MB file it gives me response perfectly. on the other hand if i upload more than 60MB file it get stuck after 100% and doesn't come in callback for sending response. and strangely file upload restart on client side. If i use start server using

```
$node server
```

it never stuck and gives me response with any file.
is there settings needs to be done on nginx config file?

Comment: There's a limit of 64MB beyond which you will have to split the file in chunks and upload those chunks. Can you check if you're not encountering this problem because of this?

Comment: this 64MB limit is on Azure side or nginx? because when i am uploading form local or using node. it gets uploaded successfully.

Comment: This is from Azure side.